# What is the reasoning behind this formula for computing an average value

Tags: probability

I have been reading the following [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17831111/).
There the formula, to compute the average longevity
$$
\overline{t}=\frac{1}{1-(p_2+p_3)}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=5}t_i p_i
$$
of a hypothetical civilization is given.

The different $p_i$ are the probabilities of events, by which the longevity of a civilization might be limited. $p_1$ is the probability that all life disappears, $p_2$ that only intelligent life disappears, $p_3$ physical or mental degradation, $p_4$ loss of interest in science and technology, $p_5$ no limits at all. Here the $t_i$ are the corresponding longevities of the different options.
My question is the term $Q=\frac{1}{1-(p_2+p_3)}$. It is called a recurrence factor and takes into account, that in the cases $p_2$ and $p_3$ another civilization might appear based on life forms, that survived past the last collapse.
Since the term $1-(p_2+p_3)<1$, dividing by it increases $\overline{t}$. $p_2+p_3$ is the probability for either 2 or 3 happening. So $p_1+p_4+p_5=1-(p_2+p_3)$ should give the probability for either 1, 4 or 5 happening. 1 & 4 limit the longevity, however 5 is no limits at all. Quite confusing.
Actually,the longevity of the no limits case is defined to be $t_5=T-T_0$, where $T$ is the age of the oldest stars and $T_0$ is the time needed to develop a technical civilization.

Could someone please explain, from the point of view of probability, how the $Q$ term might be justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUSTIFYING Q

The author supposes that with probability $p_2+p_3$ there is a collapse but that another civilisation appears **and** the author assumes that it takes negligible time to reach the same level.

The average of the longevity $L$ of the initial civilisation is, of course, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=5}t_i p_i$.

However, with probability $p_2+p_3$, the actual longevity $T$ is increased by an amount $T'$ for the replacing civilisation.

$$E(T)=E(L)+(p_2+p_3)E(T')$$ It is assumed that $T$ and $T'$ are identically distributed and so
$$(1-(p_2+p_3))E(T)=E(L)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=5}t_i p_i$$
as required.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Why did you conclude that $T$ and $T'$ are identically distributed?